# Show in feature not working

Tags: eclipse

I have two navigators in my eclipse application. And the navigators are populated with some data in tree structure. One navigator is nothing but the File system navigator which displays the project data exactly same as Windows file system. The other navigator represents the same project data in different way but tree structure only. When I right click on any of the tree element in one of the navigator and call "Show In" feature in other navigator, it is not working. If the tree is expanded then this feature is working fine. Only when the tree is not expanded it is not working. Has anybody come across this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having you sources in hands I would suggest to check that you other navigator content provider implements getParent appropriately.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Ya problem was in getParent only, thanks a lot for the solution.